# Google sheets script with API to add data after the last row with data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in google sheets that brings in data via API. Right now it is set to clear any old data in the sheet and then add the new data from the API, however in this instance I would like to be able to tell the script to look for the last row of data and the add the new API pull after the last row of data.

Below is the information that I believe needs to be changed. If anything other information is needed please let me know.

```
function setDataInToSheet(sheet, data){
  if(sheet.getLastRow() > 1)
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clear()
    
  var rows = []
  data.forEach(function(item){
    
    rows.push([item.name, item.fuelPercent.value, item.fuelPercent.time])
  })
  sheet.getRange(2, 1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
}
```

I am really at a loss and am unsure how to complete this. Thank you in advance for any assistance that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Load Data from API

```
function loadDataFromAPI() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sssId);
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dssId = dss.getId();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Source sheet
  const srg = ssh.getRange(1, 1, ssh.getLastRow(), ssh.getLastColumn());
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Destination sheet
  var vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sssId, `${ssh.getName()}!${srg.getA1Notation()}`).values;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const lr = dsh.getLastRow();
  if(lr == dsh.getMaxRows()) {
    dsh.insertRowsAfter(lr,vs.length);
  }
  const drg = dsh.getRange(lr + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length);//appends to bottom of spreadsheet
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: vs }, dssId, `${dsh.getName()}!${drg.getA1Notation()}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

The important thing for you is not to clear the sheet but just load at
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1 , 1....

Comment: Well I totally failed by not giving you enough info I'm sorry. I was trying to keep off the private info. The full script is below with your additions. I hope this helps and isnt too difficult to correct my error

Comment: Could you please explain your last comment.  I mean what do you wish me to do?

Comment: I provided the entire script this time instead of just part of the script. The API is not running properly with the new changes. The execution runs properly but nothing posts in the sheet from the API with the new changes. (in the execution log I see the API details, but I believe what is missing is the info below, I just do not know where to add it?

var rows = []
  data.forEach(function(item){
    
    rows.push([item.name, item.fuelPercent.value, item.fuelPercent.time])
  })
  sheet.getRange(2, 1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);

Comment: Sorry but I avoid most UrlFetchApp questions unless they are using Google Endpoints

Answer (score 0):

```
    function mainFunc(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = "RawData"
    var url = "https://WEBSITE"
    var data = [];
    var response = getDataFromUrl(url)
    data = data.concat(response.data)
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
}

function getDataFromUrl(url){
  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
  try{
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {Authorization: 'Bearer api'},
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
    Logger.log(response)
    return JSON.parse(response);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}

function loadDataFromAPI() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sssId);
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dssId = dss.getId();
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('RawData');//Source sheet
  const srg = ssh.getRange(1, 1, ssh.getLastRow(), ssh.getLastColumn());
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("RawData");//Destination sheet
  var vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sssId, `${ssh.getName()}!${srg.getA1Notation()}`).values;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const lr = dsh.getLastRow();
  if(lr == dsh.getMaxRows()) {
    dsh.insertRowsAfter(lr,vs.length);
  }
  const drg = dsh.getRange(lr + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length);//appends to bottom of spreadsheet
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: vs }, dssId, `${dsh.getName()}!${drg.getA1Notation()}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).